# Unbinding TokenInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

Is there any defined way to unbinding token input, the problem I am facing is that I am tracking the binding with a variable, which works in every browser, but sometime it binds element twice in IE8 only. So, I was thinking why not unbind it before binding but couldnt find any method in support documents. Any other solutions will also be appreciated.

Comment: this is what i am talking about, forgot to mention
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: see [issue](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/240) on the github issues page